# React 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, nginx, axios, postman

I am making a `POST` request **which works** if I use `postman`, like so:

```
http://localhost:5001/orders/1
```

However, trying to access the endpoint using `axios` in `React` is breaking with the following error, shown at console:

```
xhr.js:155 POST http://localhost/orders/1 404 (Not Found)

dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:155
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:49
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:55
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:74
wrap @ bind.js:11
handleSubmitOrder @ Pipeline.jsx:49
onSubmit @ Pipeline.jsx:110
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:363
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:412
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:466
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:481
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:614
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:639
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:744
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:753
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:725
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:770
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:916
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:6171
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2422
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:6271
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6301
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:674
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:11834
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22935
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2440
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6254
12:36:57.220
```

---

> FRONT

This is the form I'm using to make the request:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmitOrder(event) }>
          <div className="field">
             <input
                name="client"
                className="input is-dark is-large"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Client name"
                required
                //value={this.state.formClient.client}
                onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
              /> 
          </div>
            <div className="field">
              <input
                name="email"
                className="input is-dark is-large"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Client email"
                required
                //value={this.state.formClient.email}
                onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
              />
            </div>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="phone"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Client phone"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.phone}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="select"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Coffee ordered by client"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.select}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="button is-dark is-large is-fullwidth"
            value="Submit"
            //disabled={!this.state.valid}  
          />
          </form>
```

and this is the function `onSubmit()`:

```
handleSubmitOrder(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const data = {
      client: this.state.formClient.client,
      phone: this.state.formClient.phone,
      email: this.state.formClient.email,
      select: this.state.formClient.select,
    };
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/orders/${userId}`;
    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
```

---

> BACK

```
@orders_bp.route('/orders/<user_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def orders(user_id):
```

---

> Nginx/Docker CONFIG
>   my app in configured with nginx, and in `dev.conf` I have:

```
location /orders {
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

and in `docker-compose` config:

```
web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'

    ports:
      - 5001:5000
```

all other requests to all other endpoints works smoothly in the above configuration, except this one. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you're first line in the error message shows

> xhr.js:155 POST http://localhost/orders/1 404 (Not Found)

The URL is missing the port `5001` so I guess the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL` in your `.env` file is missing the port too?

Comment: please refer to my edit. port 5001 is there. like I said, all other endpoint with the same config work.

Comment: I would suggest to debug this, check the network tab in your devtools, and make sure the URL being called is correct with all the path parameters, after that make sure your server listening on port 5001 has this route configured as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `nginx` config.

Location `/orders` had been added to `nginx.dev` file, but changes should have been propagated building again and not merely saving it.

After I did:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --build
```

requests started working fine.